# Does apaches keep alive time-out reset every time a request is received?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, timeout, keepalive

The title of this question is pretty self explanatory, but:

Does apaches keep alive timeout reset (as in, start again) every time a request is received?

So for example, assume we have a 60 second keep alive timeout:

**Second 0 - First request recieved, keep alive starts - Timeout currently 60 seconds**

**Second 10 - Next request recieved, keep alive reset - Timeout currently 60 seconds**

OR

**Second 0 - First request recieved, keep alive starts - Timeout currently 60 seconds**

**Second 10 - Next request recieved, keep alive does not reset - Timeout currently 50 seconds**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is unclear from the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout), the timeout resets every time a response has been sent to the browser.

To be more exact, from the responses in [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50603) we can see that the timeout actually (re)starts as soon as Apache has delivered its response to the underlying OS, although that distinction isn't important in most practical circumstances.

Comment: As soon as time allows, we will do some traffic sniffing and see what actually happens. We use apache behind nginx, and nginx now supports http/1.1 + keep alives when communicating to a backend server. Since our service is fairly busy, and we have a keep alive timeout (on the apache backend) of 120 seconds, in essence what should be happening is these connections should _never_ "Connection: close". Will post update when testing done. Thanks!